# Swift NSURLSession | Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, url, swift, osx-yosemite

```
Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

When I enter a `"!"` or `"?"` my app fails to build.
This code worked in mavericks, but since I updated to **Yosemite** I get a error. 
I Believe its a syntax error but I cant find the solution.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in

        println(NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem about Yosemite, but upgrading to Xcode 6.1

`NSURL` initializer is of failable type, meaning it can return `nil` if the url passed as a string is malformed. For that reason, you have to check for not `nil` and unwrap, which you can do using optional binding:

```
var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow.com")
if let url = url { // << Optional binding
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {(data, response, error) in
        println(NSString(data: data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }
}
```